# First order by (condition) and then by (condition)

Tags: mysql

I want to order my sql request depending upon first the user's statut and then upon the username. The statut is set by the column `user_type` : 1=active, 2=inactive and 3=founder.

I would use this request to do that but it doesn't work because I want include in "active" members the actives users (1) and the founders (3) :

```
SELECT user_type, callsign, username, vid, 0php_hub_chef.hub_id AS id_hub 
FROM 0php_users 
LEFT JOIN phpbb_users ON phpbb_id = phpbb_users.user_id 
LEFT JOIN 0php_hub_chef ON 0php_hub_chef.user_id = phpbb_users.user_id 
WHERE 0php_users.hub_id = 29 
ORDER BY user_type <> 1, username_clean ASC
```

I would like something like this : `ORDER BY user_type <> 1 and 3, username_clean ASC`

Have you an idea?

Comment: Maybe this will solve your problem: `ORDER BY IF(user_type <> 1, 0, 1) ASC, username_clean ASC`

Comment: It works ! But can you briefly explain me the syntax of the `IF(user_type <> 1, 0, 1)` pls? I really don't understand why `1,0,1`.

Comment: Louis, I summarized and explained it in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `in`:

```
ORDER BY user_type in (1, 3) DESC,
         username_clean ASC
```

In MySQL, a boolean expression is treated as an integer in an integer context.  If the `user_type` is 1 or 3, then this evaluates to 1 else 0 -- hence the `desc`.

If you don't like the `desc`, you can use `not in`:

```
ORDER BY user_type not in (1, 3), username_clean
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't understand the part `IF(user_type <> 1, 0, 1)` then the same piece of code can be written using a `CASE` statement which is much more readable like below. Again you don't have to explicitly say `ASC` since that's the default sorting direction.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN user_type <> 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, username_clean
```

So essentially the code piece `IF(user_type <> 1, 0, 1)` can be written in pseudo code like

```
if(user_type != 1)
{
  order by 0
}
else
{
  order by 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please use `ORDER BY IF(user_type = 1, 0, 1) ASC, username_clean ASC` instead of `ORDER BY user_type <> 1, username_clean ASC`.

The `user_type` has the value `1` (is it an active member) the `IF`-function returns `1`. Otherwise it returns `0`. The result of `IF(user_type = 1, 1, 0)` will be used for ordering the results. The active members (user_type = 1) will be at the beginning of your result - followed by all other member types.

You can find more information about MySQL `IF` in the documentation:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if